# how to call appropriate function using function name and parameters as variables ? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, oop, parameter-passing

I want to make ajax request for fetching data to perform join operations on different tables depends on the parameters and table names.

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
     data: {fun_name: 'join_user_and_state',
            param: '12,1'
      },
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
});
```

On the server side, the action POST parameter and function name should be read and the corresponding value should point to the method to invoke, e.g.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['param']) && !empty($_POST['fun_name'])) {
   $param= $_POST['param'];  $fun_name= $_POST['fun_name'];
 // want to call proper function name with parametters from $fun_name and $param
 // parameters could be 2 or 3 or more its depends upon user choice
 // how to call
}

//definitions
join_user_and_state($user_id,$state_id)
 {
  // will do join query here with 2 tables
 }

join_user_and_city($user_id,$city_id)
 {
  // will do join query here with 2 tables
 }

join_user_and_state_and_city($user_id,$state_id,$city_id)
 {
  // will do join query here with 3 tables
 }
```

how could i call appropriate function ?

or there is any other way to achieve the same , I have to perform different different **join query depends upon user choice like user_state, user_city, user_education, user_salary..etc (and all combinations of these also possible)** ? and these columns are present in their own table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use call_user_func()

Example:

```
if(!empty($_POST['param']) && !empty($_POST['fun_name'])) {
  $param= $_POST['param'];  $fun_name= $_POST['fun_name'];
  $returnval = call_user_func($fun_name, explode(",", $param));
  //handle return variable etc....
}
```

Comment: is this approach will be fast or using if else give me fast result ?

Comment: @amitgupta it is very easy as it's just one line. If you later add more functions it will be the better approach, as with if else you need more and more if statements the more functions you have.

Comment: ok thanks, is this a good approach to handle diff join operation means different function for each join or i should make only one query and pass all the variables on the same query ? see  last 3 4 lines of my question.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve the same ?

Comment: @amitgupta you could call just one function which builds the SQL query out of the given configuration of the tables and parameters to use.

Comment: but in my case i have 5 to 6 different tables and 10 to 12 parameters from these tables so how can i build the one SQL query, how can i pass table names and parameters on one query ?

Comment: can you guide me little ?

Comment: @amitgupta Can you give me some examples of these joins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88178/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-gogolex).